# How to include submit value with jquery.form ajaxSubmit?

Tags: jquery, forms, backbone.js, jquery-forms-plugin

I have a backbone view with

`"submit": 'handleForms'`

In its events hash.

handleForms is defined as follows:

```
handleForms: function(e){
    $(e.target).ajaxSubmit({
        beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options){
            console.log('hello');
        }
    });
    return false;
},
```

One of my forms has multiple submit buttons:

```
<button type="submit" class="zone Empty" name="zone" value="14"> [14]: Empty </button>
```

"zone" is not showing up in the params being submitted to the server. According to the second bullet of the "Successful Controls" docs (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2), I would expect zone=14 to be sent.

I've seen other SO questions where people were programmatically submitting the form, so the submit value was missing, but this is being user-initiated with a button click.

Shouldn't jquery.form be including this value in the serialization? Is there a way to make it do so, or am I going to have to fish through the form elements by hand?

Comment: Tried using `<input type="submit"/>` instead of a button? also, you don't exactly have to fish... `$('form').serializeArray()` then add the appropriate button.

Comment: Good idea -- tried <input /> instead of <button>, still no dice. Trying serializeArray() on $form from a breakpoint at the console.log statement in my snippet still only yields the other form elements. (And is the same as the `arr` parameter).

Comment: you can get all the button values included with `$('form').find('input,textarea,select,button').serializeArray()` but that won't tell you which one was pressed.

Comment: Some other Googling found this jsFiddle which makes it look as if the submit-ing element is being set as the relatedTarget in `$('form').on('submit',...)` [http://jsfiddle.net/al_the_x/tnSWq/] Am I reading that incorrectly?

Comment: Yes, in that fiddle it is getting the button from the related target of the event. I would assume that would work in every browser but you'd have to test it.

Comment: Inside handleForms(e), I'm seeing:

`> e.relatedTarget
undefined`

(Same browser as I'm running the fiddle from)

Comment: at this point you should probably just accept and use one of the 2 answers that both look like they will work to me. If you can't reliably get the button, just have the button add or update a hidden field when they are activated before the form gets submitted.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is related to jQuery `serialize()` method which states in docs:

> Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button.

I believe they really mean to say not submitted by browser default method

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

You could create a workaround by appending a hidden field to the form for each submit.

```
beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options) {
    $form.find(':submit').each(function() {
        /* check if hasn't been added already on prior submit attempt*/
        if(!$form.find('input[type="hidden"][name = "' + this.name + '"]').length) {
                /* add hidden field*/
            $form.prepend('<input type = "hidden" name = "' + this.name + '" value = "' + this.value + '" / > ');
        }
    })

}
```

**EDIT** To Only send button that was clciked:

```
$('#formID :submit').click(function(){
     $('#formID :submit').removeClass('activeButton');
    $(this).addClass('activeButton');
})


beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options) {
        $form.find(':submit.activeButton').each(function() {
            /* check if hasn't been added already on prior submit attempt*/
            if(!$form.find('input[type="hidden"][name = "' + this.name + '"]').length) {
                    /* add hidden field*/
                $form.prepend('<input type = "hidden" name = "' + this.name + '" value = "' + this.value + '" / > ');
            }
        })

    }
```

Comment: Agreed, that "was not submitted using a button" statement has always been horribly open to misinterpretation.

Comment: But, surely you want just one hidden field, and to populate it with the value of the appropriate submit button when it is clicked.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot yup.. got caught up in concept and never fine tuned it. Not sure now sequence of plugin `beforeSubmit` and `input` clcik...surely `input` clcik would work..think so? I'm 95% sure it would

Answer (score 1):

How about this (not involving `beforeSubmit`):

First, hard-code a hidden field inside the form :

```
<input type="hidden" name="submitType" id="submitType">
```

Then, in js :

```
$form.on('click', "button[type='submit']", function() {
    $("#submitType").val(this.value);
});
```

Comment: that's simpler..except I noticed is `button:submit` not `input:submit`..fixed mine

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly improved code snippet for this problem, which injects a corresponding `input:hidden` tag on the fly if it doesn't exist yet, then copy value from the clicked `button` or `input:submit`.

The method should be safe on execution timings, cause `Submit` event is triggered after `Click` bubbles to the `document`.

```js
(function($) {
    var btn_selector = "form button, form input:submit";

    function _btn_handler() {
        var jo = $(this),
            jo_form = (jo && jo.closest('form')),
            jo_proxy = (jo_form.length && jo_form.find('input:hidden[name=' + jo.prop('name') + ']'));

        if (typeof jo_proxy == 'object') {
            if (!jo_proxy.length) {
                jo_proxy = $('<input type="hidden" name="'+ jo.prop('name') +'">');
                jo_form.append(jo_proxy);
            }

            jo_proxy.val(jo.prop('value'));
        }
    }
    $(document).off('click', btn_selector, _btn_handler).on('click', btn_selector, _btn_handler);
})(jQuery);
```